# Background image looks brighter on Safari

Tags: css, safari

Background image on Safari looks brighter compare to any other browsers.

When I remove `background-size: cover`, image colors looks like expected.

How do I keep normal colors and `background-size: cover` at the same time?

```
body {
    background-image: url('https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-QpCNI9iXEEE/Uq5gxSpxOJI/AAAAAAAAABM/HwVK1nETGPE/I/philadelphia_night_view.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xY9wK/

OS X Mountain Lion 10.8.3,
Safari: 6.0.3

[image]

Comment: Just checked OS X 10.7.5 with Safari 6.1, no issue. No issue on Windows Safari either.

Comment: Just upgraded to OS X 10.8.4 and Safari 6.0.5, still same issue with a little difference - when I switch Safari to full-screen - image colors restore to normal.